# Everscale-Solidity. How to get hash from data encoded into cell? tvm.hash analogue?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, everscale

Free TON Solidity. How to get hash from data encoded into cell?
*tvm.hash()* analogue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You need hash of BOC? Check this function https://github.com/tonlabs/TON-SDK/blob/master/docs/mod_boc.md#get_boc_hash

BOC with one CELL equal to CELL itself.

In fact BOC starts from root CELL which point to other CELLs.